# IdentityUI fails to load static files

Tags: c#, user-interface, identityserver4

I tried setting up a project with [IdentityUI](https://github.com/ssrdio/IdentityUI) library.

As far as I can tell everything is correctly setup, but I'm running into a small problem.
When navigating to `localhost:5000/IdentityAdmin` I get 404 errors in the browser console.

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dOYw.png)

I looks like it's having trouble loading it's static files. The admin pages loads, but without the JS and CSS files.

Has anyone already ran into a similar issue and is able to help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide the configuration example so I can reproduce the issue?